# Rails application does not start any more, but gives message about "rails new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

From one moment to another, my rails application is not starting any more. When doing `rails c`, I get the message:

```
C:\Users\mliebelt\IdeaProjects\dhm>bundle exec rails c
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
...
```

like I have called rails without any arguments. When I create a new application and go into that directory, I am able to start the rails server as usual. I have tried all variations starting it:

- rails c
- rails s
- bundle exec rails c
- ...

The versions are:

- Rails: 4.1.7
- Ruby: 2.1.4

This application has worked in the past, so my fiddling this morning with parallel development under Windows and Linux must be the reason.

I am not able to use `bin/rails s` under windows, and I have the same in the Vagrant Linux image. I am of course in the directory of the application, my application is named `dhm`. The whole structure is there, and I can use all `rake` commands as usual, but no `rails` command. So I suspect that the `rails` command is looking for something that is not there ...

What I have done in between is the following:

- I have one git repository locally in Windows, and one in my Vagrant Linux image. They are synchronized by a bare repository.
- I have switched between the 2 environments, and fixed things here or there.
- I had problems with Git, merge failed, so I fixed it by hand.

There were changes in the bin directory of the application, but I don't use that under Windows (because it does not work there). I don't have any clue how to find the reason, why the Rails application is not starting any more. Is there some flag, `--debug` or `--verbose` I could use to get more information?

Comment: You're not in the folder of a Rails project. `cd` into the right folder and try again.

Comment: Are you using rails 2?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason (hope so) why my application was not working any more. I have done the following:

1. Copied the contents of the directories app, db, config and the file Gemfile to a new created application.
2. I could then start that application as my old one.
3. I then copied back the contents of the new created application bin folder to my old application.
4. I can now start again the application with `rails s`.

The diff of the two files is:

`git diff bin/rails`

```
diff --git a/bin/rails b/bin/rails
index 215a2ea..b9f8787 100755
--- a/bin/rails
+++ b/bin/rails
@@ -1,7 +1,4 @@
-#!/usr/bin/env ruby
-begin
-  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
-rescue LoadError
-end
-require 'bundler/setup'
-load Gem.bin_path('rails', 'rails')
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
+APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
+require_relative '../config/boot'
+require 'rails/commands'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in bin/rails.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Perhaps a copy paste error (spring vs. rails) somewhere ...

So it seems not to be a good idea to work on the same application in parallel with Windows OS and Linux OS, at least the bin commands are different. I will try to write a blog post about that ...